# Any efficient way for parallel filtering on list of index in data.frame?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I have list of index in data.frame, I intend to filter out given threshold. Where reference numeric vector can be compared with threshold value and filter out vector list by parallel. How can I make this parallel filtering easily ? Can anyone propose me possible idea to accomplish task easily?

mini example :

```
myList <- list(f1=data.frame(1,2,3,4,1,1,2,4),
               f2=data.frame(1,5,2,3,4,6,1,5),
               f3=data.frame(1,4,6,7,2,3,3,5))
```

reference numeric vector:

```
globSC <- data.frame(0.33,0.325, 0.118, 0.52,0.432, 0.59,0.37, 0.63)
```

I intend to filter based on this criterion:

```
saveMe <- globSC[[i]] <= 0.5
```

my desired would be:

```
saved_idx <- list(
  f1=data.frame(1,2,3,1,2),
  f2=data.frame(1,5,2,4,1),
  f3=data.frame(1,4,6,2,3)
)

droped_idx <- list(
  f1=data.frame(4,1,4),
  f2=data.frame(3,6,5),
  f3=data.frame(7,3,5)
)
```

How can I get my expected output? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lapply

```
saveMe <- sapply(globSC, function(x) x <= 0.5)
saved_idx <- lapply(myList, function(x) x[saveMe])
droped_idx <- lapply(myList, function(x) x[!saveMe])
```